# will my visa be refused due to my history of being refused entry to the uk?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, denial-of-entry

I was denied entry to the UK for the following reasons:

- limited funding
- 'used deception' by concealing that my parents are in the UK
- no return ticket

Now the deception part I am concerned about: I mentioned that my parents are here but I don't think the officer understodd me properly and he claims that I have used deception. This is mentioned in the 'notice of refusal to leave or enter' (long paragraph)

But in the 'reasons for detention and bail rights' only the following have been ticked:

> b) there is insufficient reliable information to deceide on whether to grant you temporary admission or release
>
> 6) you have failed to give satisfactory or reliable answers to an immigration officer's enquiries.

---

so my question is, the deception was not ticked in the 'notice of refusal to leave or enter'-so does that mean it wasn't formally recorded as deception?

I am now going to apply for a visiting visa to visit my family for about a month.
How should i prepare for this to make sure that i do not get rejected?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is essentially repeating himself in 4 different questions raised in the course of two hours.  He has sufficient answers to all of the actual questions raised.

Comment: Kyle, you've asked nearly the same question again and again.  I've given info, Gayot has given info, you've asked almost the same thing again.  This is likely to be closed as a duplicate (or almost spam) - can you perhaps comment on one of the other answers if something is missing, rather than repeating the question?

Comment: @GayotFow there is some repetition, agreed, and I believe we've basically answered this already in other posts, but it's not a true duplicate, and it's certainly not off-topic.  But Kyle does need to organise his thoughts and realise that all the information is pretty much there already.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: We don't know. The only person who knows for sure is the immigration officer, and even he doesn't know until he sees your application.

The best you can do is to make sure your application is as good as it can be.

Since you've repeatedly asked similar things, let's try and sum up your questions:

[It has been recorded that I lied to the Immigration Officer, but I didn't. How can I fix this?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46137/it-has-been-recorded-that-i-lied-to-the-immigration-officer-but-i-didnt) - in your new application, do NOT lie, and DO NOT leave anything out.  Take time to explain any rejections, and make sure to include ALL relevant information they ask for.  If in doubt, INCLUDE IT.

[How long should I wait before applying for a visa after being refused entry?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46134/how-long-should-i-wait-before-applying-for-a-visa-after-being-refused-entry) - Don't wait, you can reapply now.

[What "Reason for refusal" to give in visa form when reapplying for a Standard Visitor visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46133/reason-for-refusal-in-visa-application-form) - you already know the reason for refusal - 'deception'.  Regardless of whether or not they agree, you're going to have to write that.  Of course, you can then include a letter explaining what your version of events was.

Include all that, follow all the advice Gayot has given, and perhaps get a couple of friends to read your application as well to make sure it makes sense, and apply.  That's the best option for you.  Will it get refused? Not if your reasons are valid and you've included documentation.  However, if there's more to the deception stuff than we know, they may decide you're too much of a risk.  We can't tell.

If you still have very similar questions that aren't really new questions, or if you want to clarify, do comment on the answers people have provided, or hop into the [chat] where people are happy to have casual conversations about this stuff.