# What "Reason for refusal" to give in visa form when reapplying for a Standard Visitor visa?

Tags: visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I have been denied entry to the UK and am now preparing an application form to reapply for a Standard Visitor visa. There is a section where I need to declare the reason for why I was refused entry to the UK.

I was wondering how detailed this needs to be?

There were several reasons for why I was refused - but I'm not quite sure what my main reason was.

What should I write here?

Should I just list all the points in the letter that was given to me with the paragraph listing the reasons?

I am so worried because there is a part in the paragraph that states *you have used deception to enter the UK by concealing that your parents were living in the UK* which is stupid because I told the guy but I think he heard me wrong. 
They decided to use the phrase *used deception* but I don't want the visa application to look bad because of this.

So should I just leave this part out, or write a long paragraph explaining?

Comment: 1) If (they think) you used deception in an application, you are not going to be approved (unless it was a long time ago). 2) They have access to your records. Why do you think any nuances you put on the reason are going to make a difference?

Comment: but the deception was not about using false documents or anything, there was just a misunderstanding...so what should i put in the reason for refusal section?

Comment: The reason they gave was "deception". The new form asks for the reason they gave. If you change it from "deception" to something else to make it look better, that is deception.

Answer (score 6):

The reason for refusal is not what your 'view' of the incident might be, unfortunately.  Whatever the official reason was that they gave you - in your case "deception", you have to put  that down. To do otherwise would be concealing information / lying.  Never, ever lie on an official application.  If there was more than one (we can't see the letter), write them all, IF they were different.

You're obviously worried about another denial, so in this case, provide a letter with your side of the story as an explanation.

NEVER leave it out.  That alone can be grounds for denial.

Comment: I am in a really desperate situation. my english is not good and i don't know whether my messsage will get across to immigration officers clearly. would you mind reading my letter to them? please....

Comment: @Kyle, that's not really possible on this forum. If you get enough rep (I think it's 20 or 100), join the [chat] and you might get some help there, but we can't really do it in comments or answers.