# How long should I wait before applying for a visa after being refused entry?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, visa-free-entry, denial-of-entry

I was denied entry to the UK last week (without a visa which was possible BUT was rejected for a few reasons) and was wondering how long I should wait before applying for a visitor's visa?

Is there a cooling off period?

Edit: Entry rejected because:

- failed to tell them that I have family in UK
- not enough funds
- no return ticket

In the main sheet (tick boxes) it states that I have failed to give satisfactory answers to the officer.

Comment: Not everyone will read your other question. Please put the main reasons for your rejection in this question.

Comment: thank you for your answer. my main question is, would i need to wait a while before submitting my application for a visa or should I just apply now? (it has been about a week since my entry was denied)

Comment: Please edit any additional information into the question. Don't write it in the comments. Click the 'edit' link below the question.

Comment: What makes you think you have to wait?

Comment: maybe there needs to be a cooling off period?

Comment: Even if there was, you're applying for a different visa.

Answer (score 6):

There is no required interval or 'cooling off' period that must follow a refusal (either at port or by application).

You can apply on the same day if you want.  Based upon what you wrote, you were refused entry at port and served with a removal notice (the sheet of paper with the checkboxes on it).  You have the option to apply again at a port or to seek [entry clearance](https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/entry-clearance-basics-entry-clearance-guidance) by application.

The best thing to do in these situations is to apply for entry clearance and to demonstrate that whatever caused your removal has been fixed.  This may take some time to prepare, but if you are in good shape, there's nothing to prevent your applying immediately.  If they are not satisfied that the conditions have been fixed, they will refuse again.

Comment: Hello. thank you so much for your reply. it says in the notice of removal that 'you have used deception and tried to gain entry to the uk by concealing the fact that your parents are in the uk' - i am concerned about the 'used deception part. so should i write a letter to explain why the officer may have thought i used deception? would this help my application? or will it be better if i just left it all together?

Comment: also i would really, really appreciate it if you could have a look at my other questions as they have more details of my circumstances. thank you so much for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to wait any time.  It's a different visa.

However, do note that if the visitor visa asks you anything about the rejection, or even if you're asked at the border, you may need to declare that they rejected you in the past.

The best you can do is to make absolutely sure you've included every piece of documentation they ask, in a nice, ordered fashion.  Make it easy for them to find the information in your application.  If you're not sure if you should include something - INCLUDE it.  This is from what we've seen on here, one of the most common reasons you get 'not satisfactory answers' - include all relevant information.

For example if they ask for proof of a job and you don't have one, don't just leave it out, include a letter about how you're say, starting one with x next month and include a copy of the offer.  (I'm not sure if that's on the application, but was just an example).  Too often we see people who have jsut left out a document because it put then in an unfavourable light - if you don't like how it makes you look, include an explaination.

For example, one friend's application my bank balance shows as an negative as it was a shared mortgage account, but could simply include other statements showing the mortgage and assets, and the separate savings account as proof of funds.

Stand down wise, there is no reason why you can't reapply - unless it states so in your rejection letter.  If not, prepare all appropriate documents, and go for that visa.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. would you mind looking at my recent question that i just posted? thank you so much.

Comment: @Kyle I looked at it, but Gayot is way better for that question.

Comment: thank you so much . it says i have used deception which i did not intend to do. what should i do about this? what would be the best way to explain this is a misunderstanding?

Comment: @GayotFow has answered already, I don't know better than him, do what he says - write a careful explanation of what happened.

Comment: @MarkMayo, please use 'refusal' rather than 'rejection', it helps keep everything sorted and provides a high search rank. I gave this a +1 a long time ago, it's an accurate answer.

Comment: @GayotFow I figure it helps to speak in the OP's language, and he mostly used rejection. Thoughts?

Comment: @MarkMayo, the OP will have to deal with it for a long time. Better to acquaint him with it, but overall a small point.

Comment: @MarkMayo, I forgot to add, if he writes a complaint to them and uses the wrong term, they can dismiss the complaint as unfounded. It helps their stats that they must report to Parliament.