# How long does it take to process a UK Standard Visitor Visa after a previous refusal?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, application-status

My visa was denied. I applied for a family visa instead of a tourism visa (like an idiot *hides in shame*). How long will it take to process if I reapply as I don't want to change my flight.

Comment: What's your citizenship and where are you applying from ?

Comment: South African applying in Cape Town

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have all your required paperwork, the **median waiting time is around 5 days** at the [Cape Town](https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y/cape-town-south-africa/visits-visas/general-visit-6-months-or-less) office. Also, there's no [waiting](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/46138/9551) period before you can apply again, so you can re-apply right away.

[image]

Comment: +1 though mathematically speaking the average (mean) waiting time from this data is rather somewhere less than 5.15 days and the median between 3 and 5 days. After 10 days already 99% of applications are decided i.e. most of them would be decided even faster.

Comment: @mts yeah I thought that was odd, on other pages I've seen "most applications" mean something less than 99%, must be some weighted average ?

Comment: @mts Wel, we can say that the Median is somewhere between 3 and 5 days. The mean we can't know too accuratley without knowing more about the distribution.