# Detained at Heathrow and denied entry when can I visit again

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, lhr, denial-of-entry, return

I was recently traveling to the UK to visit friends. I was detained at Heathrow and held and sent back to the US. The reason they gave is that I had past paystubs with me and a card that said good luck in your new journey. I had lots of clothes with me as I was staying for 3 months and had a return ticket. 
When can I reenter the UK? How long will I be flagged as someone who was denied entry?  I am an American citizen.  Yes they made my detention Hell.

Comment: Just curious, why did you have paystubs?

Comment: You should have been given some documentation explaining why you were being denied entry. Can you post images of that with the personal information blacked out. That should help us give you a clearer answer.

Comment: Upload your refusal letter with personal info blacked out

Comment: @jane Looks like they may have believed you were planning to work

Comment: I am asking how long will I be denied entry into the UK? I have heard there is a time limit, 'a cooling off period' and I am also asking how long will I be flagged when I travel to the UK

Comment: Also would I be ineligible for a work visa in the future?

Comment: @AzorAhai I had my latest paystub and expense check with me because I had only just received them the day before I left for the UK. I wanted to keep them with me for my personal record since they were brand new. It is just something I do incase I did not receive the right amount (for example) I would have these with me. But the border force thought that was untrue and said it was a reason to not allow me in - as if it signalled I was trying to live there.

Comment: @CannonFodder ..."not satisfied that you are a genuine visitor as required by paragraph V4.2 of Appendix V: Immigration Rules for Visitors. "

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46134/how-long-should-i-wait-before-applying-for-a-visa-after-being-refused-entry

Comment: You're going to be flagged for years. You should apply for a visa (entry clearance) from now on. Likely, you'll need to have a stable job, and not try to stay so long.