# It has been recorded that I lied to the Immigration Officer, but I didn't. How can I fix this?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, denial-of-entry

One of the reasons for my entry to the UK being refused is because I 'used deception' and concealed the fact that my parents are the in the UK. The truth is, I never lied about this: I told the officer that the purpose of my trip is to visit 'friends and family in the UK and maybe do some volunteering' but he focused on the volunteering part. The voluntary work was never my main plan, it was just a thought I had, and I told him this later but he has written in the statement that *(I) only revealed the true purpose of the trip, which was to visit friends and family, after further questioning* and *used deception to gain entry to the UK by concealing that my parents lived in the UK*.

Now, I am trying to apply for a visitor's visa but am worried I will be rejected because I supposedly 'used deception'.

i was given two sheets: `REASON FOR DETENTION` and `NOTICE OF REFUSAL TO LEAVE OR TO ENTER`. On the Reason for Detention sheet, only two sections were ticked:

(B) insufficient information to decide whether to grant you temporary admission... and
(6) you have failed to give satisfactory answers...

There is a sentence above number 6 about having used deception which has not been ticked.

Do I mention my 'use of deception' in my application for a visitor's visa?

There is a section in which I need to write why I was refused and the reasons I believe are: 1) 'deception' 2) no return ticket 3) insufficient funds.

I did not intentionally conceal the fact that my family are living in the UK (I have no reason to!) but I don't want them to misunderstand.

So what should I do?

Should I write a cover letter and if I do, what should I write exactly in the cover letter?

Answer (score 8):

When you get to question 6.5 on the application form, it asks "**Have you been refused entry on arrival to the UK in the last 10 years?**"  You should tick the YES box and provide the rest of the answers to question 6.3.

To do this, you can transcribe the reasons given on your removal notice to the form.  You should attach a copy of the removal notice to the application when you submit it.

They are not asking for a confession or an admission of guilt on your part.  As long as the removal notice does not stipulate a ban, there is no presumption of guilt either.

It's important to get all of the information accurately transcribed because when you were removed, they took your biometrics and so there will be a match on your next application.

*Everybody in the world* who gets removed for deception has a view that it didn't really happen like that.  So you can go to Part 9 of the application and provide your side of the story, they will appreciate any supporting evidence you can provide.  If you decide to give an explanation in Part 9, it is emphatically recommended that you take some time composing it BEFORE trying to fill it in on-line.  Those types of explanations can take a while to compose and the best explanations are those where the applicant wrote, slept on it, revised, repeat until it's perfect.

If they decide in your favour, they will issue an entry clearance.  Note well that if they read your explanation and decide against you, they then will be **required** to issue a ban.  It is a mandatory requirement and they have no discretion on it.  That's why it's important to do the best you can in Part 9.

If your skills in written English and advocacy are not up to scratch, you can have your explanation reviewed by a [member of the UK Law Society](http://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/) that specialises in complex case work.

The general grounds for refusal are listed in Paragraph 320 of the rules, and the governing text in your case is...

> using Deception in an application for entry clearance, leave to enter
>   or remain, or in order to obtain documents from the Secretary of State
>   or a third party required in support of the application (whether
>   successful or not);

[(Paragraph 320, sub paragraph 7b)](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/422022/20150406_Immigration_Rules_-_Part_9_v2.pdf)

Comment: it is my first time applying for a visa so please excuse me for having so many questions. is there a section where i can attach a scanned copy of the removal notice? and should i attach both the NOTICE OF REFUSAL and the REASON FOR DETENTION or just the former?

Comment: i have no supporting documents to provide except to say that i am very apologetic for not having been clear about my circumstances - is it still worth nothing this in part 9? and my english is not good so is there a sample anywhere that i cna look at? thank yuu so so much

Comment: @Kyle, what is your mother language? I may have to amend my answer...

Comment: please explain the last part of your answer...

Comment: i have 'used deception' whilst trying to enter the uk without a visa but was denied entry...but will not be doing that when i apply for a formal visa this time so does the ban still apply to me?

Comment: @Kyle, answer amended for language/advocacy skills

Comment: how much will it cost to get it reviewed by a member of the uk law society?

Comment: @Kyle, no clue.

Comment: I understand this is a huge favour but would you just read over what I have written quickly? just to see if it makes sense to you?  i would appreciate it so much ... thank you so much...

Comment: @Kyle, no. Sorry. Please read the part about 'sleep on it' again!